# EMF due to inductance?

Tags: voltage, inductance, back-emf, emf

In a DC circuit, current starts to flow, and some time is needed for current to stabilize based on the time constant, there is EMF induced due to current changing over time.

As soon as the current stabilizes there is no longer EMF due to self inductance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; as soon as the current stabilizes there is no voltage across the inductor.

The \$EMF (voltage)  = l \dfrac{di}{dt}\$; when the current is not changing, \$\dfrac{di}{dt} = 0\$; then the voltage is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Is there concept of an inductor for steady DC circuits? NO, it is a simple conductor in that case.

As already pointed out, for the initial transient phase

\$EMF (voltage)  = L \dfrac{di}{dt}\$ and as current becomes steady, \$\dfrac{di}{dt} = 0\$ So the emf is certainly 0.

What might be confusing you is the idea of magnetic field, that will still exist in steady conditions. According to Biot-Savart law (*magnetic field needs no variation of current*)

[image: (*Source: Wikipedia*)]

In this case, the device is more commonly referred to as *solenoid*, and not an *inductor*